# Split a data table into hourly totals in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data, where each row corresponds to a member of the household that takes a certain trip.
Since we are talking about members of the household, these rows can have overlapping times as seen by
row 1 and row 2. The duration of the trip is noted in minutes. The IDX is simply just an index, to make the transformation retraceable.

```
IDX  | ID   | Trip |   StartDateTime    | Duration (in minutes)
1    |  1   |  1   |  2015-01-21 13:00  | 100
2    |  1   |  1   |  2015-01-21 13:00  | 184
3    |  1   |  1   |  2015-01-21 10:00  | 91
4    |  1   |  2   |  2015-01-22 13:00  | 30
5    |  2   |  2   |  2015-01-30 23:00  | 100
```

Now I would like to split this data per id, trip, day into hourly data as follows:

```
IDX |  ID   | Trip |   StartDateTime      | Duration (in minutes)
1   |  1    |  1   |  2015-01-21 13:00    | 60
1   |  1    |  1   |  2015-01-21 14:00    | 40
```

Notice that the total duration of this group is still 100, similar to the first row. Second, the
IDX is taken from the first row. However for the 4th row, we do not have more than 60 minutes so 
that one will not be split. Resulting:

```
IDX  | ID   | Trip |   StartDateTime      | Duration (in minutes)
4    |  1   |  2   |  2015-01-22 13:00    | 25
```

The hardest problem now becomes the fifth row, that one is actually crossing a day!
So that one will become:

```
IDX  | ID   | Trip |   StartDateTime      | Duration (in minutes)
5    |  2   |  2   |  2015-01-30 23:00    | 60
5    |  2   |  2   |  2015-01-31 0:00     | 40
```

Is it possible to expand a table like that?

Code to construct the table:

```
library(data.table)

data.table(IDX = c(1:5),
           ID  = c(1,1,1,2,2),
           Trip = c(1,1,1,1,2),
           StartDateTime = strptime(c("2015-01-21 13:00","2015-01-21 13:00","2015-01-21 10:00","2015-01-22 13:00","2015-01-30 23:00"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),
           Duration = c(100,184,91,30,100)
)
```

**Update**
The starting times can be anything like 13:12, but I am not really interested in the starting time exact, so per hour actually.

So if the starting time is not equal to whole hours, such as this:

```
IDX  | ID   | Trip |   StartDateTime      | Duration (in minutes)
6    |  3   |  1   |  2015-01-30 23:14    | 67
```

then we get:

```
IDX  | ID   | Trip |   StartDateTime      | Duration (in minutes)
6    |  3   |  1   |  2015-01-30 23:00    | 46
6    |  3   |  1   |  2015-01-31 0:00     | 11
```

I am sorry for not clarifying this part, but I think this is a simple post-processing step from eddi's solution.

Thanks

Comment: Your code at the end throws a warning, fyi. Maybe it has something amiss. Also, you create a `Day` column in one part of your desired output, but it doesn't show up in the next two.

Comment: Oh sorry, that is an inconsistency! I have fixed it. In addition, the error is simply just because data.table saves the datetime in another format :).

Comment: Are start times always on the hour?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. They are accurate at the minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very similar to @eddi's answer, but using base `difftime` instead of lubridate functions:

```
# modifying the example:
DT[1, StartDateTime := as.POSIXct("2015-01-21 13:12")]

DT[,{
    t0  = StartDateTime
    t1  = StartDateTime + Duration*60

    h0  = trunc(t0, units="hour") 
    h1  = trunc(t1, units="hour") 
    h   = seq(h0, h1, by="hour")
    nh  = length(h)     

    dur = as.difftime(rep("1",nh), format="%H", units="mins")
    if (h0 <  t0) dur[1 ] = difftime(h0 + as.difftime("1", format="%H", units="mins"), t0)
    if (h1 <  t1) dur[nh] = difftime(t1, h1)
    if (h0 == h1) dur     = difftime(t1, t0)

    list(h = h, dur = dur)
}, by=.(IDX, ID, Trip)]
```

which gives

```
    IDX ID Trip                   h     dur
 1:   1  1    1 2015-01-21 13:00:00 48 mins
 2:   1  1    1 2015-01-21 14:00:00 52 mins
 3:   2  1    1 2015-01-21 13:00:00 60 mins
 4:   2  1    1 2015-01-21 14:00:00 60 mins
 5:   2  1    1 2015-01-21 15:00:00 60 mins
 6:   2  1    1 2015-01-21 16:00:00  4 mins
 7:   3  1    1 2015-01-21 10:00:00 60 mins
 8:   3  1    1 2015-01-21 11:00:00 31 mins
 9:   4  2    1 2015-01-22 13:00:00 30 mins
10:   5  2    2 2015-01-30 23:00:00 60 mins
11:   5  2    2 2015-01-31 00:00:00 40 mins
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dt[, .(IDX, ID, Trip,
       StartDateTime = StartDateTime + 60*seq(0, Duration, 60),
       Duration = diff(c(seq(0, Duration, 60), Duration)))
   , by = 1:nrow(dt)]
#    nrow IDX ID Trip       StartDateTime Duration
# 1:    1   1  1    1 2015-01-21 13:00:00       60
# 2:    1   1  1    1 2015-01-21 14:00:00       40
# 3:    2   2  1    1 2015-01-21 13:00:00       60
# 4:    2   2  1    1 2015-01-21 14:00:00       60
# 5:    2   2  1    1 2015-01-21 15:00:00       60
# 6:    2   2  1    1 2015-01-21 16:00:00        4
# 7:    3   3  1    1 2015-01-21 10:00:00       60
# 8:    3   3  1    1 2015-01-21 11:00:00       31
# 9:    4   4  2    1 2015-01-22 13:00:00       30
#10:    5   5  2    2 2015-01-30 23:00:00       60
#11:    5   5  2    2 2015-01-31 00:00:00       40
```

Here's a modification for the non-round hours:

```
dt[5, StartDateTime := StartDateTime + 14*60]

library(lubridate)

dt[, {dur = diff(c(minute(StartDateTime),
                   tail(seq(0, Duration, 60), -1),
                   Duration + minute(StartDateTime)))
      list(StartDateTime = floor_date(StartDateTime, "hour") + (seq_along(dur)-1)*3600,
           Duration = dur)}
   , by = .(IDX, ID, Trip)]
#    IDX ID Trip       StartDateTime Duration
# 1:   1  1    1 2015-01-21 13:00:00       60
# 2:   1  1    1 2015-01-21 14:00:00       40
# 3:   2  1    1 2015-01-21 13:00:00       60
# 4:   2  1    1 2015-01-21 14:00:00       60
# 5:   2  1    1 2015-01-21 15:00:00       60
# 6:   2  1    1 2015-01-21 16:00:00        4
# 7:   3  1    1 2015-01-21 10:00:00       60
# 8:   3  1    1 2015-01-21 11:00:00       31
# 9:   4  2    1 2015-01-22 13:00:00       30
#10:   5  2    2 2015-01-30 23:00:00       46
#11:   5  2    2 2015-01-31 00:00:00       54
```