# R Date Ranges Data Frame to Per Hour Sum Of Durations

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe

I have an R data frame containing the start and end times for events that looks like:

```
             timestamp        endtimestamp 
1  2018-03-27 10:00:27 2018-03-27 10:07:27 
2  2018-03-27 10:27:28 2018-03-27 10:37:58 
3  2018-03-27 10:52:59 2018-03-27 11:01:29 
4  2018-03-27 11:17:59 2018-03-27 11:27:00 
5  2018-03-27 12:03:29 2018-03-27 12:15:59 
6  2018-03-27 12:51:00 2018-03-27 13:01:30 
7  2018-03-27 13:18:31 2018-03-27 13:26:01 
8  2018-03-27 13:42:56 2018-03-27 13:50:56 
9  2018-03-27 14:08:26 2018-03-27 14:21:27 
10 2018-03-27 14:36:02 2018-03-27 14:43:58
```

I want to transform the data so that I have hourly ranges with a sum of the event durations that occur only within that hour (e.g. an event that starts in one hour and finishes in the next would only count the portions of it in each hour range) resulting in:

```
        starttimestamp        endtimestamp    duration
1  2018-03-27 10:00:00 2018-03-27 11:00:00   1471 secs
2  2018-03-27 11:00:00 2018-03-27 12:00:00    630 secs
3  2018-03-27 12:00:00 2018-03-27 13:00:00   1290 secs
4  2018-03-27 13:00:00 2018-03-27 14:00:00   1020 secs
5  2018-03-27 14:00:00 2018-03-27 15:00:00   1257 secs
```

I think I can do this with a loop though it feels clumsy but any solution I try with dplyr / magrittr doesn't seem to work.

For Example: the 1471 secs value in the result is calculated by:

2018-03-27 10:00:27 to 2018-03-27 10:07:27
= 420 secs

2018-03-27 10:27:28 to 2018-03-27 10:37:58 
= 630 secs

2018-03-27 10:52:59 to 2018-03-27 11:00:00
= 421 secs

420 + 630 + 421 = 1471 secs

Note that the final range is stopped on the hour instead of going to 11:01:29. The 01:29 is added to the next value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Code to replicate data frame:

```
test <- data.frame(IDX = c(1:10),
           timestamp = c(as.POSIXct("2018-03-27T10:00:27Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC"),
                         as.POSIXct("2018-03-27T10:27:28Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC"),
                         as.POSIXct("2018-03-27T10:52:59Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC"),
                         as.POSIXct("2018-03-27T11:17:59Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC"),
                         as.POSIXct("2018-03-27T12:03:29Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC"),
                         as.POSIXct("2018-03-27T12:51:00Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC"),
                         as.POSIXct("2018-03-27T13:18:31Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC"),
                         as.POSIXct("2018-03-27T13:42:56Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC"),
                         as.POSIXct("2018-03-27T14:08:26Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC"),
                         as.POSIXct("2018-03-27T14:36:02Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC")
           ),
           endtimestamp = c(as.POSIXct("2018-03-27T10:07:27Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC"),
                            as.POSIXct("2018-03-27T10:37:58Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC"),
                            as.POSIXct("2018-03-27T11:01:29Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC"),
                            as.POSIXct("2018-03-27T11:27:00Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC"),
                            as.POSIXct("2018-03-27T12:15:59Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC"),
                            as.POSIXct("2018-03-27T13:01:30Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC"),
                            as.POSIXct("2018-03-27T13:26:01Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC"),
                            as.POSIXct("2018-03-27T13:50:56Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC"),
                            as.POSIXct("2018-03-27T14:21:27Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC"),
                            as.POSIXct("2018-03-27T14:43:58Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC")
           ))
```

Comment: How did you get 1471 secs?

Comment: @hpesoj626 added an example calculation, hope that clarifies

Comment: Maybe similar/related https://stackoverflow.com/q/33023169/ The OP there has a "Code to construct the table" section that makes it easier to work with and would be useful here.

Comment: @Frank thanks I'll look at that now, I've added sample code to replicate the data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd maybe do...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)

durDT = test[, {
  hr  = seq(trunc(timestamp, "hour"), trunc(endtimestamp, "hour"), by="hour")
  dur = structure(rep(3600, length(hr)), units="secs", class="difftime")

  n = length(hr)
  if (n==1){
    dur = difftime(endtimestamp, timestamp, unit = "secs")
  } else {
    dur[1] <- difftime(hr[1] + 3600, timestamp, unit = "secs")
    dur[n] <- difftime(endtimestamp, hr[n], unit = "secs")
  }
  .(hr = hr, dur = dur)
}, by=IDX]

durDT[, .(total_dur = sum(dur)), by=hr]
```

which gives

```
> durDT
    IDX                  hr      dur
 1:   1 2018-03-27 06:00:00 420 secs
 2:   2 2018-03-27 06:00:00 630 secs
 3:   3 2018-03-27 06:00:00 421 secs
 4:   3 2018-03-27 07:00:00  89 secs
 5:   4 2018-03-27 07:00:00 541 secs
 6:   5 2018-03-27 08:00:00 750 secs
 7:   6 2018-03-27 08:00:00 540 secs
 8:   6 2018-03-27 09:00:00  90 secs
 9:   7 2018-03-27 09:00:00 450 secs
10:   8 2018-03-27 09:00:00 480 secs
11:   9 2018-03-27 10:00:00 781 secs
12:  10 2018-03-27 10:00:00 476 secs

> durDT[, .(total_dur = sum(dur)), by=hr]
                    hr total_dur
1: 2018-03-27 06:00:00 1471 secs
2: 2018-03-27 07:00:00  630 secs
3: 2018-03-27 08:00:00 1290 secs
4: 2018-03-27 09:00:00 1020 secs
5: 2018-03-27 10:00:00 1257 secs
```

This code should work with data where events span more than two hours (but the OP's example does not cover that case).

The hours are off from the OP due to my being in a different timezone or something.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work. The idea is to set a `base_time` from which you will deduct any excess time. Then you take the `lag` of the `excess` column so that it will match the next row of the `duration1` column. The sum of `excess` and `duration1` is `duration`. Then you sum the `duration` by the `timestamp_hour` and `endtimestamp_hour` for the final result.

```
df %>%
  mutate(timestamp_hour = floor_date(timestamp, unit = 'hours'),
         endtimestamp_hour = timestamp_hour + hours(1)) %>%
  mutate(base_time = round_date(timestamp, unit = 'hours')) %>%
  mutate(excess = ifelse((endtimestamp > base_time) & (timestamp < base_time), difftime(endtimestamp, base_time, units = 'secs'), 0)) %>%
  mutate(duration1 = ifelse((endtimestamp > base_time) & (timestamp < base_time), difftime(base_time, timestamp, unit = 'secs'), difftime(endtimestamp, timestamp, units = 'secs'))) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(excess), lag, default = 0) %>%
  mutate(duration = excess + duration1) %>%
  group_by(timestamp_hour, endtimestamp_hour) %>%
  summarise(duration = sum(duration))
```

---

### Data

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

tt <- 'timestamp,        endtimestamp 
2018-03-27 10:00:27, 2018-03-27 10:07:27 
2018-03-27 10:27:28, 2018-03-27 10:37:58 
2018-03-27 10:52:59, 2018-03-27 11:01:29 
2018-03-27 11:17:59, 2018-03-27 11:27:00 
2018-03-27 12:03:29, 2018-03-27 12:15:59 
2018-03-27 12:51:00, 2018-03-27 13:01:30 
2018-03-27 13:18:31, 2018-03-27 13:26:01 
2018-03-27 13:42:56, 2018-03-27 13:50:56 
2018-03-27 14:08:26, 2018-03-27 14:21:27 
2018-03-27 14:36:02, 2018-03-27 14:43:58' 


df <- read.table(text = tt, header = T, sep = ',')

df <- df %>% mutate(
  timestamp = as.POSIXct(timestamp),
  endtimestamp = as.POSIXct(endtimestamp)
)
```

---

### Output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   timestamp_hour [?]
  timestamp_hour      endtimestamp_hour   duration
  <dttm>              <dttm>                 <dbl>
1 2018-03-27 10:00:00.000 2018-03-27 11:00:00.000    1471.
2 2018-03-27 11:00:00.000 2018-03-27 12:00:00.000     630.
3 2018-03-27 12:00:00.000 2018-03-27 13:00:00.000    1290.
4 2018-03-27 13:00:00.000 2018-03-27 14:00:00.000    1020.
5 2018-03-27 14:00:00.000 2018-03-27 15:00:00.000    1257.
```